Is it possible to convert any map format into old NAVTEQ format?
So currently I am kinda on a mission to upgrade my old in car satnav with newer maps (I drive an Alfa Romeo 159 with Connect Nav head unit). I searched far and wide, through highs and lows of the Internet and I couldn't find any way, or any one that has managed to successfully convert any map format into an old NAVTEQ format.
The only useful piece of information that I found is that it uses the same format as the RT3 maps used by Peugeot and Citroen. That means the the successor o NAVTEQ, HERE Technologies is responsible for making those maps, since they were created in 2017.
Is it possible to convert any map format (preferably Garmin (.img) or OSM) into an old NAVTEQ one, or the one that HERE used in 2017?

Anything is possible. But that isn't really the right question, which would be more like
" How can I create data in a format that is both usable by and won't cause elderly hardware to crash."
